# reCAPTCHA ответ

Tags: php, recaptcha

Всем привет, вопрос в ответе сервера Google. Перерыл все что можно но ответа не нашел

Отправляю на обработчик, уходит нет проблем

```
function register()

$.post( "/index.php",{'username': $('#user').val(),'email' : $('#emailr').val(), 'password' : $('#passwordr').val(),'passwordConfirm' : $('#password_confirmation').val(), 'submit' :'Register', 'g-recaptcha-response' : 'grecaptcha.getResponse()',  },
```

PHP

```
$captcha = "";
    if (isset($_POST["grecaptcha.getResponse()"]))
        $captcha = $_POST["grecaptcha.getResponse()"];
         $secret = "6Lc5sjkUKmO439PmXYv";
    if (!$captcha)
        echo "not ok";
    // handling the captcha and checking if it's ok

    $response = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=".$secret."&response=".$captcha."&remoteip=".$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]), true);

    // if the captcha is cleared with google, send the mail and echo ok.
    if ($response["success"] != false) {
        // send the actual mail


        // the echo goes back to the ajax, so the user can know if everything is ok
        echo "ok";
    } else {
        echo "not ok";
    }
print_r($response);
```

Ответ

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

)]}'
["uvresp","03AO6mBfzyYSnFHNK3D6ePHChe6V13cDUvC58sHGM-zZd1KElhis-FBZTgBDkTsetLigmrhoWPHDKVX6PplG57Bcdsg0kmBBrXadJwKjnYSULBRSVh8Erq4kfW5hhAtj37orfesyx1XUSVenyxMfFyMkkxR5a7uYT0-8G7tVS-EmLeSUlWA_nDBmph38_-QseER49KkQC3XmZPPtkFIXzHkRvWY5NsbhC0YZCLs6GX18SPua1CyeehGQpqnhEvRXt74R4XU8RogmW6UByli4Wlu3gb3ZyYINPhU19QiPVL9iezYfd5590JTbKLFCNxZpy2oPAastsQ17iFF",1,120]
```

Как это можно решить?